# What is use of getInformation(),Map and Reduce Methods in Map/Reduce Script?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript

In Map/Reduce Script I, have understood the getInformation() method is used to get all the Input Data's need to process our functionality. this method returns data as {Array|Object|Search|RecordRef} inputSummary.

My Question is all the data's(Searches) need to process our functionality are to be given in this method or we can create search in other methods like Map or Reduce.

I'm little be confused on this Map/Reduce Script .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do searching and any other scripting functionality in the `map` and `reduce` phases, but that kind of goes against the purpose of the Map/Reduce script.

The purpose of each phase breaks out like this:

1. `getInputData`: Retrieve *all* NetSuite data you may need and package it into an appropriate data structure for processing (JSON, search results, etc)
2. `map`: Scan through data from `getInputData` and logically group the data for processing. NetSuite will automatically pass each group to the `reduce` phase, distributing them evenly across all available queues.
3. `reduce`: Perform actual processing of each data group.
4. `summarize`: Report out on processing results

A classic example to use is automatically creating Payments for Invoices.

1. `getInputData`: Collect all relevant Invoice data
2. `map`: Group all Invoices by Customer
3. `reduce`: Create Payments for all Customer groups

Hope this helps a little. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks Erictgrubuagh, In my process i have created the search on invoice  on the getInputData Method and i'm trying to run the search results in map and based on the search columns values , trying to create search on  another custom record and based on the obtained search columns values , trying to create a new custom record. how should i use methods in map/reduce script.